# Creating a script to look up definitions and pauses

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I wish to write a script file to look up definitions in an online dictionary from a long list of words (5000 words). I don't want my ISP or website to ban me, and also Firefox won't be able to run 5000 tabs, so I wanted to **add a pause** to the list after say about 50 searches, close those tabs, and continue then search for the next 50 words with the press of a button. I've read a lot of the posts online but I haven't been successful in getting my script to run.

This is what I have so far:

I create a script file named *words* with Mousepad, set file permissions as executable, and pasted the following into the file. Then I click the file and it runs.

It looks up the words but it doesn't pause after looking up 'stehen' (line 3) as I expect the [read](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html) command should. What am I doing wrong?

Note: This script is only a sample since I don't want to test it with 5000 words.

```
#! /bin/bash  
firefox "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=l"  
firefox "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=stehen"  
read -p "Press Enter to continue"  
firefox "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=finden"  
firefox "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben"
```

by the way, when I had Windows I had this working well. I simply added Pause! every 50 lines or so.

Answer (score 2):

This code does it:

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=l" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=stehen" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=finden" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben"
sleep 10
firefox -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=l" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=stehen"
sleep 10
firefox -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=finden" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=l"
sleep 10
firefox -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=stehen" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben"
sleep 10
firefox -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=finden" -new-tab -url "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=bleiben"
```

-Your code has Firefox open each page in a new window. The `-new-tab -url` opens each page in a separate tab. I just used some of the URLs that you had multiple times. You can adjust it with the URLs that you need.

-After closing the Firefox window, it sleeps for 10 seconds via `sleep 10`. This is the equivalent of the `pause` command in Windows. You can adjust the time if needed.

-You can replace `sleep 10` with `read -p "Press Enter to continue"` if you'd rather press enter when you want to open a new Window and tabs.

Which one it performs is up to you.